# Android more than 4 of the system, APP how to get the boot broadcast?

Tags: android

I want to do something that when I get the BOOT_COMPLETED,but now ,My application can't get the BOOT_COMPLETED.And my phone is the 4.0 sytem of Android.
Thanks!

Comment: will you please post your code here

Comment: What is your target API@Mr. Feng.We can answer if you provide proper information about your question.Please post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    // if u want to start service 
   // <service android:name="com.example.afterbootservice.MyService" > </service>

 <receiver android:name="YOUR PACKAGE NAME.BooteRecevier" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Create BooteRecevier**

```
public class BooteRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent service =  new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        context.startService(service);

       // do what u want after boot in above to line i starting service when boot comple

    }

}
```